# JNI C++ Callback from started activity

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I tried starting a new activity from C++ with help of JNI and it was started successfully. But now I need to get result of the started Activity.

Starting activity:

```
jobject activity = helper->GetActivity();
jclass activity_class = env->GetObjectClass(activity);

jclass class_intent = env->FindClass("android/content/Intent");
jmethodID newIntent = env->GetMethodID(class_intent, "<init>", "()V");
jobject intent = env->NewObject(class_intent, newIntent);

jmethodID startActivityMethod = env->GetMethodID(activity_class, "startActivityForResult", "(Landroid/content/Intent;I)V");

jint callid = (jint)  1001;
env->CallVoidMethod(activity, startActivityMethod, intent, callid);
```

So, i understand that Java calls "onActivityResult" function, but i don't understand how to override this function in C++ using JNI.

Or may be there are some other ways to take result of started activity?

I tried to get result with help of JNI function:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_package_class_onActivityResult(JNIEnv * env, jobject, jobject activity, jint requestCode, jint resultCode, jobject intentObject) {
    Logger::Instance().LogInfo(L"Java_package_class_onActivityResult");
}
```

But this function has not called (mb not overridden?)

Also I tried to call a new function create

C++ Code:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_iboxPro1C_iboxProActivity_nativeActivityResult(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobject data) {

    Logger::Instance().LogInfo(L">>>JNIEnv.Java_iboxPro1C_iboxProActivity_onActivityResult");
    Logger::Instance().LogInfo(L"<<<JNIEnv.Java_iboxPro1C_iboxProActivity_onActivityResult");

}
```

Java Code:

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaymentControllerListener {
    static native void nativeActivityResult(Intent data);
    
    //called when activity have to be finished.
    public void FinishActivity(boolean success, Intent intent) {
        Log("FinishActivity");
        setResult(success ? RESULT_OK : RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
        if (mService != null)
            mService.stopSelf();
        try {
            nativeActivityResult(intent);
            Log("nativeActivityResult NO exception.");
        }catch(Exception exc){
            Log("nativeActivityResult exception.");
            Log(exc.toString());
        }

        finish();
    }
}
```

Process just crash while FinishActivity (it isn't log anything).